# Use of 当たる in this sentence

Tags: translation, particles, verbs

Character A and B (A's coach) discuss C (A's opponent), who is known for having an amazing defense. Then C joins in and positively talks with B about A's potential. Then C drops this line:

> とにかくどこでボクと当たるかわからないけどナイスファイトをきたいしているヨ!

My translation attempt is stuck on the following options for the first half:

- "At any rate, I don't know if I'm right (that you/A could defeat me)"; in which case "どこでボクと" has no translation.
- "At any rate, I don't know if you/A is on par with me"; in which case "どこで" has no translation.
- "At any rate, I don't know if you/A can strike me anywhere"; which I would go for if the translation variation for "当たる" and the particles didn't throw me off and if I didn't worry I might be trying to squish in a translation for every word where that is not applicable.

So, some feedback would be lovely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This 当たる corresponds to the following definition from 明鏡国語辞典 2nd ed.:

> #### 当たる
>
> 競技者が、競技の組み合わせに従って対戦する。「順調に勝ち進めば準決勝でA校と━」「一回戦から優勝候補同士が━」

In English it's perhaps "will face ～", "will take on ～", "to be arranged to play with ～", etc.

Let's not ignore どこ, which is "where (in the tournament/league)". He said どこ instead of いつ because he had the list/chart/bracket of matches in his mind. Therefore:

> どこでボクと当たるかわからないけど
>   I don't know when your match with me will be, but...
>   I don't know when we're supposed to fight, but...

Comment: Wooh, seems I was way off. Glad I asked. Thank you very much for the help!